# Single-Channel (Monaural) Audio Background removal algorithms and implementations

Tags: python, matlab, audio, signal-processing

What are the best algorithms for background noise removal from an audio file?

The recordings I'm working with are monaural, the background noise is broadband and the frequencies overlap with the signals I'm interested in (simple filtering won't do).

Ones with python/matlab implementation are preferred.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This site help people with programming related questions. Your question seems to be more theory focused and I would recommend posting your questions at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/. Showing a spectral plot of your signal might also be a good idea.